# Python pandas dataframe returning NaN while defining columns name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm new in python and I'm trying to read a csv file, delete some columns that are not usefull and write it into another csv file. I manage to do this, but I want to add columns name to my csv, i'm using dataframe to do this but the values are returning NaN while i'm having real values in my tab.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('testData.csv')
x = df.drop(columns=['2','3','7','8','9','10','11'])
y = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['TimeStamp','OpenTemp','CloseTemp','MeanTemp','EndTimeStamp'])
y
```

This is my input
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvLLa.png)

And this is my output I have now
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsthW.png)

I'd like to have my values instead of NaN

Does anyone knows what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a sample input and your expected output.

Comment: if you want to **rename** the columns, just use `x.columns = ['TimeStamp','OpenTemp','CloseTemp','MeanTemp','EndTimeStamp']` and save x

Comment: Can you update your post with the 3 first lines of your csv file, please (not your dataframe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `read_csv` differently:

```
df = pd.read_csv('testData.csv', header=0,
                 usecols=[0, 1, 4, 5, 6],
                 names=['TimeStamp','OpenTemp','CloseTemp','MeanTemp','EndTimeStamp'])
```

If your csv contains header and you don't want to use it, set `header=0` and define the column names (`names=[...]`). Select the subset columns you want to keep using `usecols=[...]`.

Comment: Just to fix my answer. Can you tell me if your csv contains a header or not?

Comment: My csv contains a header. I've updated my code with your solution and it worked well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rename your columns I would recommend setting them in the existing DataFrame, and not creating a new one.

```
x.columns = ['TimeStamp','OpenTemp','CloseTemp','MeanTemp','EndTimeStamp']
```

Comment: Hi, it's not working cause my dataframe is still containg the "unnamed" columns created by my csv file, so i'm missing a column. I've tried to delete this unnamed colums but i did not manage to. The solution given by Corralien worked for me.
Thanks a lot for your help !